# Implementing SFTP in 2.0

Tags: c#-2.0, sftp

I want to write SFTP clients and servers in .NET 2.0. Is that possible? Please give me some suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx). It has an open source BSD-style license and supports SCP and SFTP.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET Framework 2.0 does not include any support for SSH/SFTP. You probably have to try one of third party solutions. Our [Rebex SFTP for .NET](http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/) can be worth checking. Check the [samples](http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/samples.aspx) and [tutorials](http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/tutorial-sftp.aspx) to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: I don't think @Martin could have been _any_ more clear about his affiliation with the company, the answer is also quite on topic and of possible use to anyone reading this question. @Pavel - people get a little sanctimonious when it comes to pixels on their screen, I suppose.

Comment: Note to 10k users: this does not constitute spam since 1. Martin discloses his relationship with the company openly, and 2. the answer is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a commercial package, take a look at [edtFTPnet/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/overview.html). It supports multiple connections, directory transfers, and lots of other neat features (I'm one of the developers on the product).

Answer (score 1):

See [SSH.NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) - it's still in development/maintained, unlike SharpSSH (unless I got bad intel)

[Sample code for uploading file](http://blog.deltacode.be/2012/01/05/uploading-a-file-using-sftp-in-c-sharp/).