# Free SFTP client with dll to upload and download file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, client, sftp

I am looking for a SFTP Client which is free. Also it should have a free dll using which I can write code to upload and download file in C# (.NET framework).

For example following code is not free, it has 30 days free evaluation, I want it for free,

```
Chilkat.SFtp sftp = new Chilkat.SFtp();

bool success;
success = sftp.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial");

sftp.ConnectTimeoutMs = 5000;
sftp.IdleTimeoutMs = 10000;

int port;
string hostname;
hostname = "www.my-ssh-server.com";
port = 22;
success = sftp.Connect(hostname,port);

success = sftp.AuthenticatePw("myLogin","myPassword");

success = sftp.InitializeSftp();

string handle;
handle = sftp.OpenFile("hamlet.xml","readOnly","openExisting");

success = sftp.DownloadFile(handle,"c:/temp/hamlet.xml");

success = sftp.CloseHandle(handle);
MessageBox.Show("Success.");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753709/implementing-sftp-in-2-0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530330/sftp-libraries-for-net

Answer (score 6):

I'm currently using SharpSSH which is free and has a very nice easy interface. [SharpSSH sourcefoge page.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh/) It has all the authentication functionality that you mentioned.

You can do this in C#:

```
var sftp = new Sftp(hostName, userName, password);
sftp.Connect(port);
sftp.Put(putFilePath, toDir);
sftp.Get(getFilePath);
```

Answer (score 4):

Would recomend to take a look at https://nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET

I think it's more up to date than sharp.ssh, works good for transmitting files through sftp.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_dotnet).  Although it is not a library, you can write scripts to drive it and the link is to a nice tutorial that shows you how to do it in both C# and Visual Basic.

Comment: Nowdays WinSCP has [WinSCP .NET assembly](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) as a .NET wrapper around WinSCP scripting interface.